# How to access correctly to php variable from a query using a modal bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table where is showed data from a table in a data base. it works but I'm using bootstrap and I added a modal element, when I press the button I get the modal with a list of items that I can choose, but I need to get the current variable and I don't know what happen. If I press the button I receive the first item of my query
 [image]

```
        <?php
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT nombre, descripcion, costo FROM tramite WHERE categoria = :categ");
        $result = $stmt->execute(array("categ"=>"tramites"));
    ?>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td><b> Nombre</b> </td>
            <td><b> Descripción </b></td>
            <td><b> Costo </b></td>
            <td><b> Oficina(s) </b></td>
            <td><b> Requisito(s) </b></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        if ($result = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            do{
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo utf8_encode($result['nombre']) . '<br>'; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo utf8_encode($result['descripcion']) . '<br>'; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo utf8_encode($result['costo']) . '<br>'; ?> </td>
                <?php
                    $nombre = $result['nombre']; // con esta variable consulto oficinas y requisitos
                    $stmtOficina = $pdo->prepare("SELECT oficina_nombreSitio FROM tramite_oficina WHERE tramite_nombre = :nombre");
                    $resultOficina = $stmtOficina->execute(array("nombre"=>$nombre));
                ?>
                <td> <?php do{ echo utf8_encode($resultOficina['oficina_nombreSitio']) . '<br><br>'; } while ($resultOficina = $stmtOficina->fetch());?>
                        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<?php echo utf8_encode($nombre); ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Añadir
                        </button>

                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Nuevo lugar</h4>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                <form>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <select class="selectpicker">
                                        <option>Mustard</option>
                                        <option>Ketchup</option>
                                        <option>Relish</option>
                                      </select>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                  <?php echo utf8_encode($nombre); ?>
                                  </div>
                                </form>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>                          

    <script>
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event)
        {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
            var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
            // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
            // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
            var modal = $(this)
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('Nuevo lugar a ' + recipient)
            modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)

        })
    </script>

                </td>
                <td> null </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
                } while ($result = $stmt->fetch());
        }
        ?>

    </table>
```

Comment: Echoing fixed html ID's and scripts in a loop is bound to lead to trouble, you should not do that. Instead move your scripts out of the loop and use classes and data attributes (if necessary...) to address the right elements.

Comment: your button has `data-target="#exampleModal"` and all of your modals also share the same id.  You should never have the same id more than once on a page.  The modal will load the first one it finds.  So make a unique id for each one by concatenating an id, like `id="exampleModal-<?php echo $result['nombre'];?>"` and use it both in your buttons and modal ids

Comment: also, for something like this, I use bootstraps remote ajax modal feature. (sadly it's going away in a future version of bootstrap)  But why load every item up front, wait until they click it to load

Comment: @RightClick I already have edited my code and now is out of the `for`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targeting id, which is problem. **Id must be page unique** and you create more same ids in the loop.

Change id target `<button data-target="#exampleModal"` to  class target `data-target=".exampleModal"`.

Then  `<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal"` to `<div class="modal fade exampleModal"`

Look at [example in bootstrap manual](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes).

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't seen the problem. now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You must add ID to each entry in database (if you don't have).

Then, in loop create modal for each entry.

```
do{
// Your table

// Button that opens modal

echo '<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#' . $result['id']  . '" data-whatever="<?php echo utf8_encode($nombre); ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">';

// Creating modal
echo '<div class="modal fade" id="' . $result['id'] . '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">';

// Continue modal ....
}
```

So, for each entry eill be generated modal with `<ID>` and you can open it with calling `<ID>`.